# is there a way to ask Rails helper functions not to produce XHTML but HTML?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, xhtml

I would like to use HTML 4.01 Strict, and used a DOCTYPE of it in my application template.  But look like when a style sheet is included by a helper function

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'style' %>
```

the code produced is XHTML:

> <link href="/stylesheets/style.css?1243210734" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

is there a way to ask Rails to produce HTML instead of XHTML?  (so that the HTML will validate for example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a quick fix to the included code above, which does work.

```
module ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper
  def tag_with_html(name, options = nil, open = true, escape = true)
    tag_without_html(name, options, true, escape)
  end
  alias_method_chain :tag, :html
end
```

Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Not really, no.

Edit: in line with my comment below, this should work (I still feel uneasy, but I can't think of anything that will break because of this)

```
module ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper
  def tag_with_html(name, options = nil, open, escape = true)
    tag_without_html(name, options, true, escape)
  end
  alias_method_chain :tag, :html
end
```

Comment: there was an old post, i later found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/595867/configure-rails-to-output-html-output-instead-of-xhtml   but the solution seems a bit hacky...

Comment: The problem with these solutions, both the one in stackoverflow and the one on railsforum is that they're just providing a default value for the `open` argument.  Plenty of Rails helpers explicitly set this to false, so the default will have no effect.

Come to think of it though, in HTML there's NEVER a need to have a self-closing tag.  So actually the examples should work if you actually just override the `close` parameter to ALWAYS be false.